# Update list content using a web part

Tags: web-part, list, list-view, content-query-web-part

I'm currently displaying content from a list using a webpart, is it possible to update the content of this list using the webpart ?

I would prefer to use an 'out of the box' web part. How can I create a link to the edit form of the List ?

Comment: Please provide more detail. What kind of web part? Out of the box or custom? If out of the box, you can create a link to the edit form of the item.

Comment: @teylyn please see questioned update

Comment: I still don't understand. How are you currently "displaying content from a list"? With what webpart? If you use a list view web part, you can click individual list items and update them. Or you can enable in-line editing. Does that not work for you?

Comment: @teylan I just want to update the field of a list via the web part directly, so display the current field value within the web part and update the value using same webpart without having to view the list item directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list view web part and enable inline editing for the list view. Then you can click the edit icon to change fields without opening the item in the list form.

[image]

With Inline Editing enabled, you can see an edit icon when you hover over the item's link field. Click the edit icon and all fields of that item will turn into edit mode. Controls like drop-downs and calendar pickers will be available, too. Edit the item values, then click the blue Save icon. Or discard your edits by clicking the red X button.

To insert a list view web part in a wiki page, edit the page and select `Insert > Web Part`. Select `LIsts and Libraries` in the Categories and then click the list for which you want to add the web part.

In a Web Part Page, click the `Add a web part` area in the web part zone to open the insert web part dialog. In the screenshot below, I am inserting a List View Web Part for a list called "InlineEditing", which is a custom list that I created to answer this question.

[image]

Comment: by 'list view web part' are you referring to a 'custom list view' with a web part used to display its contents ? As there does not seem to a content type 'list view web part' ?

Comment: I've asked that before but you did not react, so I'll ask again: In your question you say `I'm currently displaying content from a list using a webpart` - Exactly what web part are you using to do that? -- Do you know how to add a list view web part to a page? Add Web Part command, and then select the list. I'll add a screenshot above.